# Updating multiple values at the same time SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update multiple values at the same time,

Table values

```
UniqueRef, Name
1101, AA01
1102, AA02
1103, AA03
```

I want to update UniqueRef for all of 1101, 1102 and 1103 to different values e.g
1101 will be updated to 1101AB ect

how can I do this in bulk than one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a single `UPDATE` statement:

Seems like you need to update `UniqueRef` in a single pattern. So use following statement:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET name = CONCAT(UniqueRef, 'AB');
```

This will update all rows - in case you need to limit the scope use `WHERE` statement and define appropriate condition.

In case you need to use different values for each row use `CASE` statement in

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET name = 
  CASE
    WHEN UniqueRef = 1101 THEN 'newValue' 
    WHEN UniqueRef = 1102 THEN 'anotherNewValue' 
    {nextStatements} 
    ELSE name
  END
;
```

Comment: Tried this however not working.

Comment: @AndyThomas "Not working" is one of the least helpful phrases in IT. Please specify ***exactly*** what isn't working (show an example from dbfiddle, copy and paste error message, etc). Imagine phoning a car mechanic and saying you car "is not working" and expecting them to tell you what's wrong, how to fix it, or give a repair quote.

Comment: so I've tried this query:
Update TableName
SET UniqueRef = CASE 
WHEN UniqueRef = 1101 THEN 'NewValue'
WHEN UniqueRef = 1102 THEN ' NewValue2'
END;

But then the table updates to the rest of the UniqueRef Column tables that are not included in the above statements to NULL

Comment: Edited to remove typo (copy and paste error having multiple CASE keywords) and add ELSE to avoid wiping out every other row's Value with NULL (though a WHERE clause would be better ELSE should still also be used for safety)

Comment: @AndyThomas https://dbfiddle.uk/dv4wVTmD

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for your effort in improving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The scalable solution is to use UPDATE with a JOIN on a source for the new values (usually another table, but it can be an online view, such as below)

```
UPDATE
  example
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 1101 AS id, 'X' AS new_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1102, 'Y'
)
  AS update_map
    ON update_map.id = example.uniqueRef
SET
  example.name = update_map.new_name
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/g71hwuYG